# Qt new Project Files not displayed

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I add new files to an existing Qt project the files don't show up in Qt Creator's directory tree until I close and reopen the project.

This behavior only concerns one of the projects I am working on which by now contains more than 800 files (including sources and all resources). Sadly I can not remember when this behavior started to occur.

It is so far not reproducible. If I add files to a fresh project they show up in the tree view right away. Can this be a problem concerning the project settings, or could this be a settings issue with Qt Creator?

I suspected the Mercurial plugin, since I use Mercurial for version control. However deactivating it has brought no improvement.

Comment: Are you using cmake? I have seen similar behaviour on cmake projects.

Comment: No, I am using qmake. No cmake in this or other projects.